# Can you create an Azure VM Scale Set from custom image in an Image Gallery using the Portal?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

When I create a new Scale Set in the portal it just gives VM image options from the market place.  Is it possible to create a Azure VM Scale Set using a custom image stored in an image Gallery using the portal?  Basically [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-use-custom-image-cli) but using the portal.

Answer (score 0):

NVM just found it.  Have to click "All Images" then "My Images" then it will show images stored in Galleries.